# Ionic 3 missing Navigation URL

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am beginner for Ionic . Just started my first project a one month ago and it is almost in completing stage and then I realized that my app is always pointing to `localhost:8100` when I run `ionic serve`.

Example - on landing on the home page, the URL should be `localhost:8100/#/home`
on moving to the appointments page, it should change to `localhost:8100/#/appointments` 
but no matter what page I am in, it says `localhost:8100`

I am using lazyloading. I have included lazyloaded modules into `app.module.ts`. I have included the app page, IonicPageModule import and exports in my lazyloaded module. I have used `@IonicPage({name: ‘name’, segment: ‘name’})` in the `component.ts`.

app.module.ts -

```
import { AppointmentsPageModule } from './../pages/appointments/appointments.module';
import { AppointmentsPage } from './../pages/appointments/appointments';
...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AppointmentsPage,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    AppointmentsPageModule
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AppointmentsPage,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

appointments.module.ts -

```
import { AppointmentsPage } from './appointments';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [

  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(AppointmentsPage)
  ],
  exports: [
    AppointmentsPage
  ]
})
export class AppointmentsPageModule {}
```

and included this in appointments.ts -

```
@IonicPage({
  name: 'appointments',
  segment: 'appointments'
})
```

And I am using

```
this.navCtrl.push('appointments');
```

I have been searching for a solution for this in all of google and Ionic Worldwide Slack but have not been able to find a solution. Please assist.

Ionic CLI version - 4.0.3
Cordova version - 8.0.0

Comment: What is the issue. please ellaborate

Comment: Im not clear what do you asking , anyway what is your root page ,example `rootPage:any = TabsPage;` look at your `app.component.ts`

Comment: @core114 `rootPage:any = HomePage;`
My question is that for navigation (in PWA build / web build), I need the URL to be updated because there are services section on the website that will link to the specific page in the application I am building. The URL is not updating when I push a new page or set a RootPage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some digging around blog posts, ionic docs and collecting pointers from @MDM, I finally arrived at a solution and got it to work on my app. This is what I did -

app.module.ts => **DO NOT import any page here. In fact there is no need to import any page in any ts file in the whole project**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
   // No need to import any pages.
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    // No need to import any lazy loaded modules
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    // No need to import pages here either
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

lazy loaded page.module.ts file => **Any page, module you import for that particular lazy loaded page will go here**

```
import { AppointmentsPage } from './appointments';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppointmentsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(AppointmentsPage)
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    AppointmentsPage
  ],
  exports: [
    AppointmentsPage
  ]
})
export class AppointmentsPageModule {}
```

**NOTE** I have declared the page, imported the module AND exported the page.

And in the page.ts file, before the `@component` decorator =>

```
@IonicPage({
  name: 'AppointmentsPage',
  segment: 'appointments'
})
```

**I have added the name as 'AppointmentsPage' as i felt it would be easier for me to make changes in all my push/setRoot/Popovers and Modals, but this is your choice to make!**

Finally pushing to the page =>

```
this.nav.push('AppointmentsPage');
OR
this.nav.setRoot('AppointmentsPage');
OR
this.popoverCtrl.create('AppointmentsPage');
```

**Note: Notice how we need to include the page name in single quotes**

To summarise all this,

1. You do not need to import any page component/use it anywhere
2. You do not need to import any page module into your `app.module.ts`
3. You do not need to declare any component in the `app.module.ts`
4. You need to enter the page name like so `'MyPage'` instead of `MyPage`(which
   will require you to import the page).

Comment: I still get "no component factory found" after I remove my page module from the app imports. Is there an additional step?

Comment: Nope, there is no additional step to this.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing all the pages and modules in **app.module.ts**. Import your pages to that particular module only and also don't import your modules to **app.module.ts**.

In your code, if you are using lazy loading, declare 'AppointmentsPage' in **appointments.module.ts**, not in **app.module.ts**. Also don't import AppointmentsPageModule in **app.module.ts**.

If you generate page with command 'ionic generate page Appointments', ionic automatically handles all of this, you need not manually import all these.

In this way, navigating to 'AppointmentsPage' will update the url localhost:8100/#/appointments.

Comment: 1. I tried importing that particular page in the lazy loaded module, but on entering the app, it says `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for TransactionsPage. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?`.
2. I did generate the page with the Ionic CLI `ionic generate page appointments`
but still on navigating to the appointments page, it does not change the URL

Comment: Might be you are missing  exports: [ TransactionsPage ] in TransactionModule

Comment: For better understanding of Lazyloading, i will suggest you to create new sample project and generate any two pages with this generate command and don't add name and segment in @IonicPage(). If url gets changed then make necessary changes.

Comment: No, page exports are mentioned in all the page.module.ts file.

For your second suggestion, i tried downloading a pre-made theme project as well, yet, face the same issue. Tried with creating a fresh Blank project, still same issue. Is it any sort of a dependency issue? global packages, etc. I don't really know

Comment: Can you paste your app.module.ts here?

Comment: I had to add entryComponents to all lazyloaded module.ts files (which was not added by default when generating the page via CLI command). It is working now :)